# Calculate the integral of $\frac {\exp(z)}{\sin(z)}$ over $|z|=4$ using the residue theorem.

Tags: exponential-function, complex-integration, trigonometric-integrals

[Click to view the integral in correct format.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9z9E.png)

Calculate the integral of $\frac {\exp(z)}{\sin(z)}$ (as in the image above) over the positively oriented circle defined by $|z|=4$ using the residue theorem.

This is a question that I'm just not sure I'm doing completely correct and would like some confirmation or correction. Pictures of my work are added below.

From $\frac {\exp(z)}{\sin(z)}$, the singularities within $|z|=4$ are $0$, $\pi$, and $-\pi$ where $\pi$. I used the residue theorem with the $p(z)$ and $q(z)$ standards where $\operatorname{Res} (f, z_0) = p(z_0)/q'(z_0)$ to get

$$\operatorname{Res} (f, 0) = \frac{e^z}{\cos z}_{|z=0} = 1$$

$$\operatorname{Res} (f, \pi) = \frac{e^z}{\cos z}_{|z=\pi} = -e^{\pi}$$

$$\operatorname{Res} (f, -\pi) = \frac{e^z}{\cos z}_{|z=-\pi} = -e^{-\pi}$$

Thus, the residue theorem yields the (unsimplified) answer of $2\pi i (1-e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi})$.

[Click to view the guidelines I assumed to start my calculation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A17A7.png)

[Click to view my calculations and answer in a more legible format.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrEXb.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: Thank you for getting me up to speed with the site standards! I've added my calculations as well as links to my work in a more readable fashion. Hope this satisfies the guidelines and helps to see where I might be going wrong in my work!

Comment: As promised, I retracted my close vote :)

Answer (score 1):

Your computations of the residues are correct. And the computation of the integral (via residue theorem) also looks fine.